# Rails generates chart for .each do |x| using highcharts or any other chart API

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts JS to display tables of companies ATM.

I'm displaying list of companies in one single page :

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
```

I tried to render one chart, and put the

`<div id="someid" ...> </div>`

in side the

`.each do |company|`

ONLY the first chart is generated, I am assuming that the `renderChart()` only works once, so if I put `<DIV ID="someid" >` multiple times, only the first one is working.

how do I solve this problem?

I've found an example to display multiple charts, http://jsfiddle.net/pebch/
but even with the above example, it has to manually do renderChart() three times, and each  is with different ID's

How to do this automatically using data from database?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: thanks Jordan!

so now I have

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <div id="staffchart-<%= company.permalink %>" ...></div>
<% end %>
```

and in my Highcharts JS, i have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var charts = new Array;
jQuery.fn.renderChart = function(attr) {
  i = charts.length;
  var chart = charts[i] = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: $(this).attr('id'),
    },
    series: attr.series,
  });

}
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#staffchart-microsoft').renderChart({
          series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Random data1',
            data: [<% StaffLevel.where(:company_permalink => "microsoft").each do |staff_level| %> 
              [Date.UTC(<%=  staff_level.created_at.strftime("%Y,%m,%d") %>), <%= staff_level.number_of_employees %>],
            <% end %>],
          }],
        });

        $('#staffchart-apple').renderChart({
          series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Random data2',
            data: [<% StaffLevel.where(:company_permalink => "apple").each do |staff_level| %> 
              [Date.UTC(<%=  staff_level.created_at.strftime("%Y,%m,%d") %>), <%= staff_level.number_of_employees %>],
            <% end %>],
          }],
        });

        $('#staffchart-twitter').renderChart({
          series: [{
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Random data3',
            data: [<% StaffLevel.where(:company_permalink => "twitter").each do |staff_level| %> 
              [Date.UTC(<%=  staff_level.created_at.strftime("%Y,%m,%d") %>), <%= staff_level.number_of_employees %>],
            <% end %>],
          }],
        });
```

so Companies with name twitter/apple/microsoft is displaying correctly now. 
but thats hard coded in,  how to make this section automatically judging by data from database, instead of me coding => "twitter" , and write .renderChart() for many times manually?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code ? it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the same `id` for multiple elements in the same document. This is the (X)HTML spec and there's no way around it.

The solution, as you have discovered, is to use a different `id` for each element (Highcharts doesn't seem to support using a class selector instead of `id`). This is easy enough to accomplish in Rails. For example:

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <div id="container_<%= company.id %>" ...></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Will also need to instantiate each chart by the new id container_xxx in the Javascript as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <% @companies.each do |company| %>
  $("#staffchart-<%= company.permalink %>").renderChart({
      series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Random data1',
        data: [<% StaffLevel.where(:company_permalink => company.permalink).each do |staff_level| %> 
          [Date.UTC(<%=  staff_level.created_at.strftime("%Y,%m,%d") %>), <%= staff_level.number_of_employees %>],
        <% end %>],
      }],
    });
  <% end %>
```